# What linux tools are suitable for reducing power consumption on mainboard (or its peripherals)?

Tags: command-line, motherboard

I set cpu clock multiplier to 10 so cpu top clock frequency is at most at 1GHz. That limits mainboard top consumption to ~24Watts. There is nothing like that for gpu, usb, pcie, thunderbolt or network devices, that would suspend these at bios level. So maybe there is some tooling from userspace for switching off/limit power for these devices?

What command line tools or commands for linux based operating systems (os) are available for reducing power consumption on common desktop mainboard peripherals (for e.g. suspend peripherals from user space)?

Answer (score 0):

`powertop` comes to mind - this tool will provide you with numerous suggestions for saving power, and should let you enable them conveniently too. It is likely to be in your distribution's repositories already, so installing it should be a breeze.